# Не могу создать Blob через метод createBlob()

Tags: java, база-данных, sqlite, mysqlconnector

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "1";
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Java_project\\Rabota_s_basami_dannix\\database";
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

        System.out.println("Connection establish");

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("img.jpg"));
        Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
        OutputStream outputStream = blob.setBinaryStream(1);
        ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

        PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into carblob(name,speed,img) values(?,?,?)");
        statement1.setString(1,"BMW");
        statement1.setInt(2,200);
        statement1.setBlob(3,blob);
        statement1.execute();

    }
  }
}
```

Вот стэк-трейс исключения:

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.createBlob(JDBC4Connection.java:75)

at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:24)

Comment: Поменяйте базу данных

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом [setBytes](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/):

```
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream =
                 new FileInputStream(
                         new File("2018-10-17 22_16_32-Best Practices for Sencha Javascript Applications on Vimeo.png"))) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
        fileInputStream.read(bytes);
        System.out.println(bytes.length);
        try (PreparedStatement statement1 =
                     connection.prepareStatement("insert into carblob(name,speed,img) values(?,?,?)");) {
            statement1.setString(1, "BMW");
            statement1.setInt(2, 200);
            statement1.setBytes(3, bytes);
            statement1.execute();
        }
    }
```